# Cordova/Phonegap external page load start page

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to come back to my application after redirecting to an external page.

I'm loading www.external.com in the same webview (view the setting OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView = YES).
It's not an issue with the whitelist rejection, the host is configured with the external hosts plist setting.

The www.external.com contain a simple :

```
<?php
$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);     
header('Location: ' . $url);   
?>
```

And then I want to come back to index.html#my/route
The problem is that the absolute path of the main phonegap page is :

```
file:///var/mobile/Applications/48D1C223-FD34-436E-85BE-8C0B58859ECF/MyApp.app/www/index.html#my/route/
```

And I get (either on Simulator or on device) a security error:

```
Failed to load webpage with error: You do not have permission to access the requested resource.
```

I can't use window.history.back() because I redirect more than one time.
By the way, the window.history.back() is working, I come back to my app.

I'm using cordova 2.1 on xCode 4.5.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you, by chance, figured this out already? I am running into the exact same scenario and have not found much great information on dealing with it.

Comment: I'm on it today... #crossfingers

Comment: Three years later - does anybody have a solution to this?!

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the reason I created [cordova-plugin-startpage](https://github.com/aabluedragon/cordova-plugin-startpage).

Call the `startpage.loadContentSrc()` plugin method and it should redirect you back.